# i don't know why my function can not read quotesdata

Tags: javascript

i don't why my function in addEventListener can not read quotesdata ,
this what i see in the console :

**Uncaught TypeError: quotesData[currentQuote] is undefined**
and this is js code :

```
quotesData = [
    {
        quote : `There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.`,
        name : 'Albert Einstein '
    },
    {
        quote : `Good friends, good books, and a sleepy conscience: this is the ideal life.`,
        name : 'Mark Twain'
    },
    {
        quote : `Life is what happens to us while we are making other plans.`,
        name : 'Allen Saunders '
    },
    {
        quote : `It's not the load that breaks you down, it's the way you carry it.`,
        name : 'Lou Holt'
    },
    {
        quote : `Try not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.`,
        name : 'Albert Einstein '
    },   
]
/* important variables */ 
let currentQuote = quotesData[0];
const quoteText = document.getElementById('quote');
const quotebtn = document.getElementById('q-btn');
const quotespan = document.getElementById('q-span');

/* this the main function its usefulness is show a quote from quotesData evrey time you click on the button*/ 
quotebtn.addEventListener('click' , () => {
    quoteText.innerText = quotesData[currentQuote].quote;
    quotespan.innerText = quotesData[currentQuote].name; 
    
    currentQuote = (currentQuote + 1 ) % quotesData.length;
});
```

Comment: Your `let currentQuote = quotesData[0];` statement seems incorrect. I believe you wanted to assign the index 0 to it but instead you are assigning an object here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the index, not the object of the current quote in `currentQuote`:

```js
quotesData = [
    {
        quote : `There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.`,
        name : 'Albert Einstein '
    },
    {
        quote : `Good friends, good books, and a sleepy conscience: this is the ideal life.`,
        name : 'Mark Twain'
    },
    {
        quote : `Life is what happens to us while we are making other plans.`,
        name : 'Allen Saunders '
    },
    {
        quote : `It's not the load that breaks you down, it's the way you carry it.`,
        name : 'Lou Holt'
    },
    {
        quote : `Try not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.`,
        name : 'Albert Einstein '
    },   
]
/* important variables */ 
let currentQuote = 0;
const quoteText = document.getElementById('quote');
const quotebtn = document.getElementById('q-btn');
const quotespan = document.getElementById('q-span');

/* this the main function its usefulness is show a quote from quotesData evrey time you click on the button*/ 
quotebtn.addEventListener('click' , () => {
    quoteText.innerText = quotesData[currentQuote].quote;
    quotespan.innerText = quotesData[currentQuote].name; 
    
    currentQuote = (currentQuote + 1) % quotesData.length;
});
```

```html
<button id="q-btn">New quote</button>
<div id="q-span"></div>
<div id="quote"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think that you may be using the key ` and not the key '. I think that you might want to change all of the quotes at the beginning and end to " just to be safe. I'm probably not right, but it's the only solution I can think of.